# Only allow a-z and space and the first letter of each word to be capitalized

Tags: php, regex

Someone sitting on a regex that only allows a-z and ONLY allow the first letter of each word to be capitalized?

So 'Im detective John kimble" would be match but "Im a Cop yOu iDiot" would not be allowed

Comment: I hope John McEnroe doesnt want to eat at McDonalds than.

Comment: Shouldn't `detective` be written as `Detective`, if it is a valid case ? Same is the case for `kimble`.

Comment: Look at here: http://rubular.com/r/X8DmfHjCdY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will match a word with a lower-case or capital letter at the beginning of the word.

```
[a-zA-Z][a-z]*
```

Now you can extend the regex to match multiple such words depending on what exactly you want. You have to be a bit careful with this to make sure it handles strange cases like an empty sentence etc.

```
([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)* // Matches the empty sentence as well
([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)+ // Must have at least one word
```

Then you need to consider if the start and end characters (`^` and `$`) are relevant for your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In css you can capitalize the 1st letter of each word with:

```
.title {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

In PHP the string function [ucfirst](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) like this:

```
$foo = ucfirst($foo);
```

Allows only `a-z` use this regex in Javascript

```
var pat = /^[a-z]+$/;
```

Comment: I dont wanna capitalize every word then i would just have used phps ucwords. I only wanna allow the first letter of each word to be capitalized

Comment: OP is looking to validate input, not change characters I think

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need regex for this that .. because i don't really think how is is an offence

You can simple correct the case :

```
$str = "joHn KiMBle";
echo ucwords(strtolower($str));  // John Kimble
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)+
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern to check that:

```
^(?>[A-Za-z][a-z]*+|[^A-Za-z]++)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Doable without regex.

```
!(strspcn($text, "0123456789") !== false || 
  ucwords($text) == ucwords(strtolower($text)))
```